# Bootstrap in Single Page App

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, durandal

I'm building a Single Page Web App and want to use bootstrap UI components.
My understanding is that bootstrap script runs in page load and checks the classes applied to html tags and converts them into bootstrap controls.
If I'm building a single page app with view composition (like Durandal), and want to run Bootstrap after the view is composed in the DOM, how do I do that?
I want to keep declarative syntax in html (i.e. apply bootstrap classes like dropdown), and I don't want to call .dropdown() function on the DOM element explicitly.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this? My experience is that it actually works right out of the box.
I have been working on a number of SPA apps and they work absolutely fine.

The Durandal sample project also uses Bootstrap for its UI if you want to download that and take a look.

Bootstrap makes use of the JQuery "On" handler to ensure that dynamic dom content added later on after the page has finished initially loaded is handled and bound correctly.

Comment: It works, but I don't know how :). I'm missing something, can you please explain when the bootstrap.js code runs in case of view composition?

Comment: I just searched for the Jquery on() method, and I guess this could be the answer ...

Comment: Ah yes sorry, I have edited the answer to include this... The ON handler is a great way of ensuring all dom elements added after page load are handled correctly. Have fun!

Comment: Note that tool-tips and pop-overs are opt-in, so you will probably want a knockout binding to enable those.   The knockout-bootstrap library can provide these for you: http://billpull.github.io/knockout-bootstrap/#tooltip